# How to plot vector addition in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

I am trying to plot vector addition and I am not getting the result as expected, I am completely new at 3D plotting I need serious help
My plot looks like this:
[image]

What I want is to connect the green line to the head of the two arrows. My code looks something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

u = np.array([1, 2, 3])   # vector u
v = np.array([5, 6, 2])   # vector v:
  


fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection = "3d")

start = [0,0,0]
ax.quiver(start[0],start[1],start[2],u[0],u[1],u[2],color='red')
ax.quiver(start[0],start[1],start[2],v[0],v[1],v[2])
ax.quiver(v[0],v[1],v[2],u[0],u[1],u[2],color="green")
ax.set_xlim([-1,10])
ax.set_ylim([-10,10])
ax.set_zlim([0,10])



plt.show()
```

Apologies for any kind of mistake , thnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's vector addition, just add the vectors

```
sum_vector = u+v
ax.quiver(start[0], start[1], start[2], sum_vector[0], sum_vector[1], sum_vector[2],  color="green")
```